# JavaScript: Why do I keep getting this error with a literal object custom method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, object-literal

`ctx` is predefined along with other canvas properties. I didn't want to bombard the page with a huge chunk of code.

I'm building an array of literal objects and they have one method. When I try to call the method it says that It's undefined, like this:

```
var enemiesArray = [];

function createEnemy(ene) {
    for (e = 0; e <= ene; e++) {
        var t = Math.floor(Math.random() * 291)
        var p = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
        var enemies = {
            x: t,
            y: p,
            hp: 20,
            dir: 0,
            damageImage: function () {
                return "bomber4.png";
            }
        }
        enemiesArray.push(enemies);
    }
}
//an interval is set to call the following function:
function drawEnemey() {
    for (zdp in enemiesArray) {
        img = new Image();
        img.src = "Images/" + enemiesArray[zdp].damageImage(); //this is where I get the    error.
        img.style.width = "20px";
        ctx.drawImage(img, enemiesArray[zdp].x, enemiesArray[zdp].y);
        //move from side to side
        if (enemiesArray[zdp].dir == 0) {
            //move left
            enemiesArray[zdp].x -= 1;
            if (enemiesArray[zdp].x <= 0) enemiesArray[zdp].dir = 1;
        } else {
            //move right
            enemiesArray[zdp].x += 1;
            if (enemiesArray[zdp].x >= 290) enemiesArray[zdp].dir = 0;
        }
        //check if they are hit
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is when I run the code as is,`enemiesArray[zdp].x` through `enemiesArray[zdp].dir` are defined, but `enemiesArray[zdp].damageImage()` isn't.

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org Please use it.

Comment: You're using the wrong statement for Array iteration. Try changing this `for (zdp in enemiesArray) {` to this `for (var i = 0; i < enemiesArray.length; i++) {`

Comment: And use `var` in for loop variable initializations please.